# What is the more appropriate way to use iOS keychain technology

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, keychain

I'm not fully understand the techniques around iOS keychain technology. What is the more appropriate way to use it?

Suppose that I have the wrapper for the iOS keychain like this -- https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith and I want to save the user credentials (email and password) for the later use.

Ok, I have the following function from the specified wrapper:

```
func saveData(data: Dictionary<String, String>, forKey key: String, inService service: String, forUserAccount userAccount: String) -> (NSDictionary?, NSError?) { /* ... */ }
```

I thought that the best way to call this function is the following:

```
Locksmith.saveData(self.passwordTextField.text, forKey: "password", inService: "AppName", forUserAccount: self.emailTextField.text)
```

but I noticed that the first argument is a dictionary. What should be the key for this dictionary? If this is the "password" what should be the argument for the "forKey" parameter then?

And am I right that the argument for the "inService" parameter should be the name of the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the keychain itself as a dictionary, where you can store objects based on some key.  In this case the key is a combination of a key, a service and a user account.  Rather than limiting you to storing a single value per "key", the library allows you to store a dictionary.

So, in your case you could store a dictionary with a single entry - the user's password for the key "password", but the flexibility is there to store additional entries.

A common use of Keychain is store a record of in-app purchases.  In this case you could store a number of product identifiers and a quantity purchased for each, as an example.

Comment: So, the following will be the best solution in my case -- `Locksmith.saveData(["password": self.passwordTextField.text], forKey: "UserCredentials", inService: "AppName", forUserAccount: self.emailTextField.text)`, am I right?